# MapStruct seems to create too many method

Tags: java, spring, mapping, dto, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct v 1.4.1.Final to map Hibernate entities to corresponding DTOs. I'm using Spring Boot, so my mapper's classes have the `componentModel` equals to `spring`.

I have 2 entities, `Person` and `Address`. `Person` contains an `Address` instance:

**Person**

```java
public class Person {
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

```java
public class PersonDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private AddressDto address;
    private String role;
}
```

**Address**

```java
public class Address {
    private String addr;
    private String city;
}
```

```java
public class AddressDto {
    private String houseAddress;
    private String city;
}
```

and here are the mappers I wrote:

**Mappers**

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AddressMapper {
    @Mapping(source="person.username", target="userName")
    @Mapping(source="address.addr", target="address")
    DeliveryAddressDto personAndAddressToDeliveryAddressDto(Person person, Address address);

    @Mapping(source="person.username", target="userName")
    @Mapping(source="person.address.addr", target="address")
    DeliveryAddressDto personToDeliveryAddressDto(Person person);

    @Mapping(source = "address.addr", target = "houseAddress")
    AddressDto addressToAddressDto(Address address);
    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "addressToAddressDto")
    Address addressDtoToAddress(AddressDto addressDto);
}
```

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {AddressMapper.class})
public interface PersonMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "username")
    @Mapping(source = "address.houseAddress", target = "address.addr")
    @Mapping(source = "role", target = "role.id")
    Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto);
    List<Person> toPeople(List<PersonDto> personDtos);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "toPerson")
    PersonDto toPersonDto(Person person);
    List<PersonDto> toPeopleDto(List<Person> people);

    /**
     * update an existing Person with Dto info.
     * Set infos on the existing object (Person), without creating a new one.
      */
    @Mapping(source = "role", target = "role.id")
    void updatePersonFromDto(PersonDto personDto, @MappingTarget Person person);

}
```

where you can see that I said to the `PersonMapper` to use the `AddressMapper` to use its implementations.

However, for the conversion of the address to the address dto I found another implementation in the `PersonMapper` class (same for the inverse mapping):

### AddressMapper implmementation

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-11-21T15:44:55+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class AddressMapperImpl implements AddressMapper {

    @Override
    public DeliveryAddressDto personAndAddressToDeliveryAddressDto(Person person, Address address) {
        if ( person == null && address == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        DeliveryAddressDto deliveryAddressDto = new DeliveryAddressDto();

        if ( person != null ) {
            deliveryAddressDto.setUserName( person.getUsername() );
        }
        if ( address != null ) {
            deliveryAddressDto.setAddress( address.getAddr() );
        }

        return deliveryAddressDto;
    }

    @Override
    public DeliveryAddressDto personToDeliveryAddressDto(Person person) {
        if ( person == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        DeliveryAddressDto deliveryAddressDto = new DeliveryAddressDto();

        deliveryAddressDto.setUserName( person.getUsername() );
        deliveryAddressDto.setAddress( personAddressAddr( person ) );

        return deliveryAddressDto;
    }

    @Override
    public AddressDto addressToAddressDto(Address address) {
        if ( address == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto();

        addressDto.setHouseAddress( address.getAddr() );
        addressDto.setCity( address.getCity() );

        return addressDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Address addressDtoToAddress(AddressDto addressDto) {
        if ( addressDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Address address = new Address();

        address.setAddr( addressDto.getHouseAddress() );
        address.setCity( addressDto.getCity() );

        return address;
    }

    private String personAddressAddr(Person person) {
        if ( person == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Address address = person.getAddress();
        if ( address == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        String addr = address.getAddr();
        if ( addr == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return addr;
    }
}
```

### PersonMapper implementation

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-11-21T15:44:55+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class PersonMapperImpl implements PersonMapper {

    @Autowired
    private AddressMapper addressMapper;

    @Override
    public Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto) {
        if ( personDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Person person = new Person();

        person.setAddress( addressDtoToAddress1( personDto.getAddress() ) );
        person.setRole( personDtoToRole( personDto ) );
        person.setUsername( personDto.getId() );
        person.setName( personDto.getName() );

        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> toPeople(List<PersonDto> personDtos) {
        if ( personDtos == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>( personDtos.size() );
        for ( PersonDto personDto : personDtos ) {
            list.add( toPerson( personDto ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonDto toPersonDto(Person person) {
        if ( person == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();

        personDto.setAddress( addressToAddressDto1( person.getAddress() ) );
        personDto.setId( person.getUsername() );
        personDto.setRole( personRoleId( person ) );
        personDto.setName( person.getName() );

        return personDto;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PersonDto> toPeopleDto(List<Person> people) {
        if ( people == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<PersonDto> list = new ArrayList<PersonDto>( people.size() );
        for ( Person person : people ) {
            list.add( toPersonDto( person ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePersonFromDto(PersonDto personDto, Person person) {
        if ( personDto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( person.getRole() == null ) {
            person.setRole( new Role() );
        }
        personDtoToRole1( personDto, person.getRole() );
        person.setName( personDto.getName() );
        person.setAddress( addressMapper.addressDtoToAddress( personDto.getAddress() ) );
    }

    protected Address addressDtoToAddress1(AddressDto addressDto) {
        if ( addressDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Address address = new Address();

        address.setAddr( addressDto.getHouseAddress() );
        address.setCity( addressDto.getCity() );

        return address;
    }

    protected Role personDtoToRole(PersonDto personDto) {
        if ( personDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Role role = new Role();

        role.setId( personDto.getRole() );

        return role;
    }

    protected AddressDto addressToAddressDto1(Address address) {
        if ( address == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto();

        addressDto.setHouseAddress( address.getAddr() );
        addressDto.setCity( address.getCity() );

        return addressDto;
    }

    private String personRoleId(Person person) {
        if ( person == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Role role = person.getRole();
        if ( role == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        String id = role.getId();
        if ( id == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return id;
    }

    protected void personDtoToRole1(PersonDto personDto, Role mappingTarget) {
        if ( personDto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        mappingTarget.setId( personDto.getRole() );
    }
}
```

In this implementation, **why the method `addressDtoToAddress1()`** is created? Why is not used the `addressDtoToAddress()` provided in the `AddressMapper` implementation? Those methods are identical.

Please also note that the `AddressMapper` is injected in the `PersonMapper` and the method `addressDtoToAddress()` of the `AddressMapper` is called in the method `updatePersonFromDto()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying an address mapping twice in your `PersonMapper`.

```
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "username")
@Mapping(source = "address.houseAddress", target = "address.addr")
Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto);
```

You're stating that `PersonMapper` should use the `AddressMapper`, but instead you add another override mapping to map the fields manually.

You can just remove the mapping and it will find the correct one by itself.

```
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "username")
Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto);
```

If you want to add an explicit mapping, you'd need to pick the source as `PersonDto`'s address field to target `Person`'s address field. Below will give the same result.

```
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "username")
@Mapping(source = "address", target = "address")
Person toPerson(PersonDto personDto);
```

It works fine in the `updatePersonFromDto()` because you didn't add an override of it and it picked it up the `AddressMapper` by itself. You'll notice the same behaviour if you add the same redundant mapping to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't notice that mistake! If I remove the mapping it's working as expected :)